# .NET XmlSerializer XML format

Tags: .net, xml, format, xmlserializer

Is there a way to make XmlSerializer to serialize object' properties as attributes
instead of as elements ?

like:
Person.Phone="1 800 CALL ME"

would become:

[Person Phone="1 800 CALL ME" /]

instead of:

[Person][Phone]1 800 CALL ME[/Phone][/Person]

Comment: By implementing IXmlSerializable you can control exactly how the object i serialized.

Comment: @Magnus that is usually a bad way to do it; very hard to do robustly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure...

```
public class Person
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Phone {get;set;}
}
```

You can also change the name/namespace etc by looking at the attribute parameters.

Comment: Thank you. I believe this was the first answer advising to use XmlAttribute. Kind of not sure, most answers show "2 hours ago" but "Oldest" tab ranks this one on top.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way

```
[Serializable]
public class Person
{         
      [XmlAttribute()]
      public string Phone { get; set;}

      Or

      [XmlAttribute("Phone")]
      public string Phone123 { get;set;}
}
```

Comment: XmlSerializer does not check for  (and does not require)  `[Serializable]`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [XmlAttribute attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.aspx)